# cast variable of protocol type over to another type that conforms to that protocol

Tags: swift, generics, architecture, protocols

Lets say I have the following protocol and two structs that conform to that protocol:

```
protocol BasicAnswerProtocol {
    var id: Int { get set }
    //...
}

struct TextAnswer: BasicAnswerProtocol {
    var id: Int
    let answer: String
}

struct NumberAnswer: BasicAnswerProtocol {
    var id: Int
    let answer: Int
}
```

Then I have a var called current that I want to conform to the BasicAnswerProtocol, but it should be possible to have it either of type TextAnswer or NumberAnswer.

Now I want to cast this current variable over to either TextAnswer or NumberAnswer inside of a view, but when I do that I get the error:

> Cast from 'Binding<BasicAnswerProtocol?>' to unrelated type 'Binding<TextAnswer?>' always fails

This is the view code:

```
struct myView: View {
    var current: Binding<BasicAnswerProtocol?>

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            if let c = current as? Binding<TextAnswer?> {
            //error: Cast from 'Binding<BasicAnswerProtocol?>' to unrelated type 'Binding<TextAnswer?>' always fails
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

So any idea how I could give a variable a type that can be "changeable" but restricted to conforming a certain protocol?

If I set current of generic type T, I get into another problem which is that I have to set T somewhere, in a typealias for example. And once it is set I can't see how that can be changed. All help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not using `@Binding` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Binding<SomeType>`, use the `@Binding` SwiftUI property wrapper. This will bring a lot of benefits, and it's also the idiomatic way in SwiftUI.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @Binding var current: BasicAnswerProtocol?

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            if let c = current as? TextAnswer {
                // you have a text answer here
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Well I get the same warning: "Cast from 'BasicScreenProtocol?' to unrelated type 'TextAnswer' always fails". I also want to pass a binding variable over to the child view, not a var of type TextAnswer.

Comment: @DevB2F `BasicScreenProtocol`? Thought we were discussing about `BasicAnswerProtocol` :). Also, you can pass the binding downstream via `$current`. You should really go through the Apple tutorials on SwiftUI, they are great.

Comment: You're right about that, I pasted your answer into a wrong view. That warning is gone. Thank you! But now I can't send c as binding using $c, only $current. Since c is now not a binding type.

Comment: @DevB2F you might need to do some re-design then, SwiftUI is mostly about data, introducing protocols like this only help in complicating things. Try to re-design your view hierarchy so that it uses the concrete types instead of protocols.